# how to get string with maximum of three words in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, nlp

I have a list of different strings with different number of words in each string, I want to be able to get string with maximum of three words from the list,

This is the list of strings below

```
['organised crimes perpetrated globally using sltd .“',
 'major system supporting arm manned',
 'united states national central bureau',
 'interpol police global system',
 'national central bureau',
 'global community .“',
 'tracking system domiciled',
 'interpol global system',
 'nigerian sltd detection',
 'successfully yielded result',
 'statement made available',
 'mr muhammad babandede',
 'lost travel documents',
 'deliberate acts leading']
```

This is the output I'm expecting Expected output:

```
['national central bureau',
 'global community .“',
 'tracking system domiciled',
 'interpol global system',
 'nigerian sltd detection',
 'successfully yielded result',
 'statement made available',
 'mr muhammad babandede',
 'lost travel documents',
 'deliberate acts leading']
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.split` and check its length

```
sentences = ['organised crimes perpetrated globally using sltd .“', 'major system supporting arm manned',
          'united states national central bureau', 'interpol police global system',
          'national central bureau', 'global community .“', 'tracking system domiciled', 'interpol global system',
          'nigerian sltd detection', 'successfully yielded result', 'statement made available',
          'mr muhammad babandede', 'lost travel documents', 'deliberate acts leading']

result = [sentence for sentence in sentences if len(sentence.split()) <= 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not used to the one-liner formatting from azro, you can simply unfold it:

```
result = []
for sentence in sentences:
  if len(sentence.split()) <= 3:
    result.append(sentence)

print(result)
```

Comment: i understand the list comprehension as is even the best option i have always prefer.... thank you for the response